# IE9 whitespace css and alignment

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-9, vertical-alignment, html-table

The problem I am having is that I need to keep the whitespace on the TD text while still vertically aligning the text within the TD. When the `white-space: pre-wrap` is enabled, the text is bottom justified within the TD. And if I disable that tag then IE takes that all but one space out between each letter.

```
<td width="10%" class="someClass" style="white-space: pre-wrap;">    
    hh    ee  lll oooo
</td>
```

Here is the CSS for that

```
.someClass {
  text-align: left;
  text-indent: 0px;
  padding-top: 1px;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
  font-size: 1em;
}
```

Comment: if you wrap your text in `pre` tags, your spacing should be preserved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you wrap your text in pre tags, your spacing should be preserved

```
<td width="10%" class="someClass" style="white-space: pre-wrap;">    
    <pre>hh    ee  lll oooo</pre>
</td>​
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BLSully/hb4aU/2/

Comment: this seems to over exaggerate the size of the spaces vs using the pre-wrap in CSS. they both have the same number of spaces but the <pre> tags causes the text to cover a wider area

Comment: that's because `pre` by default uses a mono-space font. in your css you can do something like `td pre { font-family: inherit; }`